# Azure Virtual Machine for SPFx Development

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, azure, spfx-tooling

As my personal laptop is too slow, is it possible to setup dev environment using Azure Virtual machine for SPFx Development?

Kindly provide your advice on the same.

Comment: Just curious: Why use Azure VM for SPFx development?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Azure virtual machine for SPFx development.

All you have to do is setup a SPFx development environment as explained in below documentation:

[Set up your SharePoint Framework development environment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment)